# A reference to the DLL could not be added in .net compact framework for WIN CE platform

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, compact-framework

I have created a Dll project (file-> New->project->VC++->win32 smart device project for WIN CE) in .net compact frame (project options with SDK installed)

When I add the .dll file as a reference in another C# win forms WIN CE project it shows an error :

A reference to the "....dll" could not be added.?

how to use this vc++ DLL (.net compact Framework 3.5) in C# project?

In short:

how to create a DLL with C++ code, that should be ported on to C# .net Compact frame work (WIN CE platform)?

Thanks for any hints/replies. !!

Comment: VC++ .NET is not supported by the Compact Framework. So it is not possible to have a .NET CF c++ dll. You need to edit your question. What version of the CF are you using with what language. What version of .NET is the application you are trying to import the DLL and what language.

Comment: I am working on CF 3.5 (for WIN CE) Platform, then how to make the c++ DLL to support the CF 3.5 C# project?

Comment: In short:

how to create a DLL with C++ code, that should be ported on to C# .net Compact frame work (WIN CE platform)?

Comment: Ok, I understand now. You want to create a C/C++ dll that you can use on the device and call from a C# application. 1. You need the Platform SDK from the device maker. Locate and install it. 2. File->New->Project->VC++->Win32 smart device. Add SDK from step 1, select DLL, select "Export symbols". 3. Create a simple test function in your DLL add extern "C" to all function declarations in your header. 4. Compile it for your SDK. 5. in C# application do not add reference to the DLL. You use the DLL with P/Invoke `[DllImport("yourdll.dll")]`, put the DLL on the device with your C# application.

Comment: thanks !!

DllImport will work for only APIs right??

then how to use the variables, defines & structures etc., that are defined in DLL ?? is it possible?

Comment: You re-create the structs from your C headers in your C# code. Sometimes you will have to take care on how to define the structs to make sure that everything Marshals correctly. You will want to review MSDN's introduction to P/Invoke and Marshalling. You cannot use C++ Classes in .NET with P/Invoke. You can only use API functions. Inline's and macro's cannot be used. You can always create a C function that "wraps" an inline function or Class functionality and P/Invoke that call. For example, a function for each class method, which takes a pointer to the class to get around that limitation.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to use C/C++ methods in C# you will need to P/Invoke the methods you require. If you have your own C++ assembly that you want to use, you need to make sure you have some kind of C interface to it.

Here is an example of P/Invoke on a user32 method:

```
[DllImport( "user32.dll" )]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool EnumWindows( EnumWindowsProc lpEnumProc, IntPtr lParam );
```

You [PInvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/) has alot of already generated signatures for standard assemblies (kernal32, user32, GDI32, etc..).

Other Links:

- [MSDN Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- [Code Project: P/Invoke Tutorial: Basics](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/403285/P-Invoke-Tutorial-Basics-Part)

Answer (score -2):

right click on project select properties 
in Application area check the Target frameworks make it .Net Framework 4

do this steps in both projects the original project of dll file 
and the project you need to add the dll file to it

Good Luck

Comment: There is no version 4 of the CF

Comment: I always wonder how less people know about compact framework diffs to full framework.